# Bend mesh around object without loosing dimensions

Tags: shrinkwrap

So i know there a lot of post about this. But i cant get it to work.

Right know i follow some other post and do a lattice with shrinkwrap and then connect the mesh to the lattice. But i still lose the dimensions. First i did try only shrinkwrap, also did try curve, but im kinda new to blender so a bit hard.

So how to solve this a want the mesh to wrap/curve around the other object.

Im also losing the radius att the end of the mesh, i dont want that.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: if you just want to bend this object you could use a Simple Deform modifier (Bend mode)

Comment: Well its not a perfect circle and bend is perfect circle right? Also It seems that bend makes the dimensions change, i want to keep them.

Comment: in that case maybe simply duplicate the faces of the circular object and use them to create it?

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can give a try: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: No that will not work. I need to use a template, like and image or svg. Then bend it, and keep the lenght the same (350mm)

Comment: a Curve modifier seems good to me, you just have to duplicate an edge that has the shape you want, convert to curve, then use it as the target of your Curve modifier